# Talking about the future in the sense of 'prediction as order'

Tags: future-tense

There is the following rule, relating to talking about the future:

> Prediction can be used as a way of giving orders - instead of telling
>   somebody to do something, the speaker just say firmly that it will
>   happen. This is common in military-style.

Let I'm explaining somebody the working principle of a something device. Does the rule applied to that case. That is, for example

> A device **shall** reset every one hour.

In general, it would be good if you provide a bit more examples reflecting the rule.

Comment: According to my own experience, "Something *shall* do something or be something" is quite common in software specifications and requirements. It's a way to state some requirements firmly that those requirements must be implemented and/or will definitely happen. -- Another note, I think it's rare find "A device shall reset ..." in written documents, I believe that "A device shall *be reset* ..." is better.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when you use the *verb* for the third person (he, she or it), the better choice is *will* and not *shall*. [The explanation with example is here on the OxfordDictionaries.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/shall-or-will)

This said, the answer is finished.

> A device **will** reset hourly.

But it's good to know that a common military-style uses *shall* that way. Imagine an alien in a sci-fi movie confidently telling his army - `"There shall not live any person on the earth peacefully. Go, destroy everything"`

Comment: It's a bit unclear. There is an example from technical documentation _The value of the first parameter shall be interpreted as the requested size of the allocation._ What mean of that shall is? Is it prediction as order?

Comment: here, it's working as *should/is* This use is different from that *military-style*.